# What is the difference between ondomready and jquery's ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is the [link](https://github.com/tubalmartin/ondomready) to ondomready github repo.I couldn't understand the AMD term in it.
Forgive my ignorance, but what advantages does it bring compared to jQuery's ready function?

Comment: it's mentioned:: "Based on jQuery's ready() method (same behavior & reliability)", so its the same ...!

Comment: @Sudhir:Then why was it made?

Comment: For programmers who don't want to load all of jQuery.

Comment: Well, the author might have wanted to avoid usage of jQuery.. i guess

Comment: @Barmar:Does it include jquery?Or is it just using parts of jquery?Is it used to decrease download bytes?

Comment: @Aravind Do you know what vanilla JS is?

Comment: @Pinocchio:Sorry, I don't know!I'm looking at its documentation now.Could you give me a brief overview?

Comment: No, it doesn't include jQuery, that's the whole point. It's a tiny library that just does this one thing, instead of the Swiss Army Knife of jQuery.

Comment: if you want to know how it works, just read the code.

Comment: @Barmar:That makes sense! But why does such a fundamental operation have to depend on jquery's version updates?

Comment: It doesn't depend on anything to do with jQuery. It just does the same thing as jQuery's ready method.

Comment: @Barmar: This statement from the github page:
"Easy to maintain: Since onDomReady is based on jQuery's implementation, whenever the jQuery team improves it onDomReady will be updated." got me confused.

Comment: They don't mean it happens automatically, they mean they're going to keep an eye on jQuery updates -- if the jQuery team makes any changes to this, they'll update their code to be compatible.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it doesn't give you any advantages, you would only use this if you're writing **pure** Javascript.

As it does say right here

> Based on jQuery's ready() method (same behavior & reliability).

So it would be literally the same.

> My personal opinion is that I think it was made for the **vanilla** framework. Here is the
>
> **Link: http://vanilla-js.com/**

Comment: where is that second quote from? Or is it just a formatting abuse?

Comment: Well, you see. I have the code-review site theme installed on stackoverflow. and the quotes look absolutely gorgeous. http://d.pr/i/ATJJ

Comment: Am I not allowed to create my own quotes?

Comment: I could let it slip as not confusing if you make it clear you are quoting yourself ;-)

Comment: facepalm @Pinocchio :-)

Comment: If it follows the same interface, it doesn't even matter whether it's copied verbatim or not.